# SyncML server for contact/calendar synchronisation

Tags: calendar, synchronization

I'm currently looking for some kind of server that allows me to sync my calendar/contacts between several different programs. All of those have one thing in common: They all support SyncML.

Now the bad part: As far as my search capabilities took me, I found two servers that support SyncML: Funambol and Horde.

To be honest, I don't like Funambol very much, mostly because it seems like you need an X server to configure it.

And for some reason I'm not able to successfully configure Horde.

Now, for the time being, I'm hoping that someone has a different software for this task. I really only need to synchronize calendars/contacts via SyncML, a web interface would be an added extra but not neccessary and the software/server should run on a Debian 7.